# jquery parseJson returning null

Tags: jquery, json

I'm trying to parse the following json using jquery...

```
{
    "notificationhistory": [
        {
            "userid": "Richard",
            "createdtime": "2014-10-01T15:20:55",
            "actiontype": "Y",
            "note": "Richard test",
            "actioncode": "AC",
            "lastmodified": "2015-04-28T10:52:28"
        }
    ]
}
```

My jquery function to try and do this looks liek this....

```
function loadNotificationBarData() {
    var url = "json/notificationBar.action";
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            var json = $.parseJSON(data);               
            alert(json.notificationhistory[0].actiontype);
            alert(json.notificationhistory[0].actioncode);
            alert(json.notificationhistory[0].note);               
        }
    });
}
```

But this is not working for me. I keep getting a null for my var json.

Can someone help me with this please?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless I'm mistaken, jQuery `$.ajax` already parses the data to `json` automatically for you, so just remove the `var json = $.parseJSON(data);` code as its not needed

Answer (score 1):

Try a different Syntax

```
var result = JSON.parse(data);
```

Comment: yes i think it might have been the name of the variable... thanks

Answer (score 0):

this worked [Online Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sw4yb3og/1/)

```
function loadNotificationBarData() {
    var data = {
        "notificationhistory": [
            {
                "userid": "Richard",
                "createdtime": "2014-10-01T15:20:55",
                "actiontype": "Y",
                "note": "Richard test",
                "actioncode": "AC",
                "lastmodified": "2015-04-28T10:52:28"
            }
        ]
    };              
    alert(data.notificationhistory[0].actiontype);
    alert(data.notificationhistory[0].actioncode);
    alert(data.notificationhistory[0].note);    
}

loadNotificationBarData();
```

Comment: thank you. this also helped me. I think it was the name of the variable. I noticed you didn't use parseJson? This got me thinking when or why is it necessary to use parseJson?